# Free software web hosting control panel (alternative to cPanel/Plesk)

Tags: linux, open-source, web-hosting-control-panel

I need to manage a server, common task are:

- Create virtual apache servers
- Create FTP accounts
- Create mail accounts
- Log monitoring
- Quota management

I am wondering what is the best free software web-based config tool to do it (webinar, zpanel, gnupanel, ispconfig, etc...). It is a hard decision and once you have started using one it will difficult to migrate the server to other.

Comment: Webmin is by far the most developed and extensible free product right now, but it suffers from serious problems like steep difficulty, learning curve, update difficulty, etc.

If you're doing this for yourself for a test server, it might be the best option. If it's a production server for a company—get them to fund a paid product :) all three major paid systems (cPanel, Plesk, DirectAdmin) are significantly easier to learn, teach and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot say that I have surveyed a large enough sample of alternatives in order to claim that this one is "the best," you might want to consider [**Webmin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmin). I discovered this nice, modular, and extensible configuration tool through my use of [TurnKey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/), where it is built into each of the numerous software appliances offered.

As documented in the list of [Webmin "modules"](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Modules), Webmin has modules for managing each of the areas that you asked about -- [Apache](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Apache_Webserver), [FTP](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ProFTPD_Server), [mail](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Postfix_Mail_Server), [logs](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/System_Logs) (see [also here](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Log_File_Rotation)), [disk-quotas](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Disk_Quotas) -- and many more.

Answer (score 1):

## [CentOS Web Panel](http://centos-webpanel.com/) (CWP)

I've used this for the past month or two and it works great. Good user inteface.

Downside is that it only works on CentOS based OSes.

Answer (score 1):

How much ram do you have in your server? Since you're asking for a web-based panel, make sure you have enough space on your server end for the installation of such kind of big stuff.
Otherwise, why not try a desktop-based panel, like this one - [VPSrobots](https://vpsrobots.com/),
it works well with my two Vultr servers(start plan which offers 1GB RAM, 20GB storage), which are too samll in size to accodate anything optional that is larger than 500MB.